# How do I copy a materialized view to a table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, materialized-view

I have a materialized view. I want to create a copy of it so I can modify some of the data to test a few theories about an issue and its possible solutions.

How do I make a copy of this MV as a table? The copy will reside in the same schema but will have a different name. the copy should be an identical copy (structure and data) of the MV, it's just going to be a table so I edit the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`

```
CREATE TABLE your_new_table_name
AS
SELECT *
  FROM your_materialized_view
```

If there are indexes on your materialized view that you want to create on the table, you'd need to create those separately.

Comment: Not sure why SO believe I voted your answer down. There's nothing wrong with it, but I can't change "my" vote since it is locked :-(